# Fluent interface building different concrete types

Tags: c#, fluent, fluent-interface

I need some suggestions on how to build a fluent interface acting as a Builder, responsible for returning different concrete types depending on the methods called.

Imagine that I need to create one of the following types using my ProductBuilder (fluently): Product, ServiceProduct, PackagedProduct (both derived from Product).

I'm thinking of using a fluent syntax like this (other suggestions are more than welcome):

To create a Product:

```
var product = new ProductBuilder()
   .Create("Simple product")
   .WithPrice(12.5)
```

To create a ServiceProduct

```
var product = new ProductBuilder()
   .Create("Service product")
   .WithPrice(12.5)
   .AsServiceProduct()
       .ServiceProductSpecificMethods...()
```

And PackagedProduct with a call to AsPackagedProduct() instead of AsServiceProduct() etc. You get the idea.

I haven't found a sample that shows best practices on this. Only samples where the final build returns the same type.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have a complete set of requirements for this interface?  and are you looking for assistance organizing them into a fluent interface?

Comment: What is the builder pattern really buying you here? What *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive: I'm wondering how a call to e.g. AsServiceProduct() "informs" the Build method on the ProductBuilder to actually create an instance of ServiceProduct with its specific attributes (supplied by subsequent method calls on the builder, after AsServiceProduct()) instead of a Product in it simplest form. I could set a private property in the AsServiceProduct method telling the builder to create a ServiceProduct instead of a Product, but I'm thinking there's a better solution than that.

Comment: @32bitkid: Nothing in this simple case. I'm looking into the way of designing these interfaces in order to determine if it will be of any use to us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options here.

If there are a finite number of products that are fixed, and not designed to be extended, then just create a `Create` method for each product:

```
var product = new ProductBuilder()
   .CreateSimple()
   .WithPrice(12.5);

var product = new ProductBuilder()
   .CreateService()
   .WithPrice(12.5)
   .ServiceProductSpecificMethods...();
```

If you don't want (or can't have) `ProductBuilder` to know all of the types of products, then I would use generics:

```
public class Product {}
public class SimpleProduct : Product {}
public class ServiceProduct : Product {}

var product = new ProductBuilder<SimpleProduct>()
   .WithPrice(12.5);
```

Here's a starting place for the design to follow:

```
public class Product
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
public class SimpleProduct : Product { }
public class ServiceProduct : Product
{
    public string Service { get; set; }
}

public class ProductBuilder<T> where T : Product, new()
{
    private List<Action<T>> actions = new List<Action<T>>();

    public T Build()
    {
        T product = new T();
        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            action(product);
        }

        return product;
    }
    public void Configure(Action<T> action)
    {
        actions.Add(action);
    }
}

public static class ProductExtensions
{
    public static ProductBuilder<T> WithPrice<T>(this ProductBuilder<T> builder, decimal price)
        where T : Product
    {
        builder.Configure(product => product.Price = price);
        return builder;
    }

    public static ProductBuilder<T> WithService<T>(this ProductBuilder<T> builder, string service)
            where T : ServiceProduct
    {
        builder.Configure(product => product.Service = service);
        return builder;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is an interesting solution Servy. Thank you very much. It does however require the setters of the Product attributes to be public/protected. Do you see a way of avoiding that?

Comment: @TommyJakobsen Well, the easy way would be to make everything that causes mutation to be `internal` and move all of this into it's own .dll.  To avoid that you'd probably end up only ever returning interfaces, rather than concrete objects, or using reflection (so that you could make the setters private and still access them outside the class).

Comment: Was afraid of that answer :) But yes, I can see why and there's probaly no way around it.

Comment: @TommyJakobsen The other option would be to make all Product types immutable.  It would be fairly simple to make all of the Actions Funcs which return a new product with the added value instead.  In reality I consider fluent syntax to be primarily useful for immutable datatypes; for mutable data types you may as well just use a more traditional syntax.

Comment: No doubt about it, and I think that you're right that a more traditional syntax would be the best in this case. But your approach is nice, and it might come in handy at some point. Thank you for sharing it. I'll leave the question open for a day or two to see if other approaches will come up.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you correctly I would use generics here so I can write something like:

```
var product = new ProductBuilder()
.Create<Serviceproduct>()
.WithPrice(12.5)
   .ServiceProductSpecificMethods...()
```

You may also add Build method before calling specific service methods so it will actually create final product:

```
var product = new ProductBuilder()
.Create<Serviceproduct>()
.WithPrice(12.5)
.Build()
   .ServiceProductSpecificMethods...()
```

Comment: What will the Create<Serviceproduct>() method return? In your second example, does the call to Build return an instance of a ServiceProduct? In that case you're Building an invalid ServiceProduct because required attributes needs to be set on the builder (through method chaining) before Building the ServiceProduct, to ensure the builder always builds a valid product.

Comment: Sorry for late response. The idea of first (simple) approach is that you create Serviceproduct on .Create<Serviceproduct>() call and the use extension methods to configure product and then call specific methods. Extension methods should have well defined contraints to work correctly.

Comment: In the second example idea is pretty the same as in answer from @Servy. ProductBuilder().Create<Serviceproduct>() will return class ProductBuilder<Serviceproduct> (can be taken from answer @Servy). Actually the only difference you will have new ProductBuilder().Create<Serviceproduct>().WithPrice(12.5).Build() vs new ProductBuilder<SimpleProduct>().WithPrice(12.5).Build(). And you will have one extra class with my implementation.